# How I can to define in UE4 the default values of variables published by UFUNCTION

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have a proeject in C++ with UE4 and I need to know if there is a way to define the default value of C++ variables when I use this function from Blueprints.

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = SirenPlayerCameraManager)
virtual void SwitchCameraTo(ACameraActor* CameraActor, EViewTargetBlendFunction BlendFunc, float BlendTime);
```

This is my Function, and when I use this Blueprint I want the parameter BlendFunc could have a default value != 0

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible 
just like in plain C++ you can assign a value for example

```
 UFUNCTION(...)
 void F(int x = 0);
```